# Multi-room chat problems with node.js and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have been working on a basic multi-room chat setup with node, socket.io, and express. Basically I want people to be able to join rooms by going to any url like, `http://domain.com/room/123` and they would join the room 123 in socket.io. So someone could join any number room potentially and send that link to their friends.

The actual html file where they are in chat is `http://mydomain.com/room.html`.

After looking over some other code for similar setups, I put something together but I am not sure of a few things because it is not working as I am intending.

Here is the relevant code:

--- for the server ---

```
var PORT = 3000;
var app = require('express')(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(PORT);

app.get('/room/*', function (req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/room.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

socket.on('user_join', function(username, room_number){
    socket.username = username;
    socket.room = room_number;
    socket.join(room_number);
});

socket.on('send_message', function(message){
    socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('update_chat', socket.username, message);
});

socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    socket.leave(socket.room);
});


});
```

And here is some of the relevant code from the client main html page:

```
// Gets the 123 out of /room/123
var room = window.location.pathname.substring(6);
var socket = io.connect("http://mydomain.com:3000/room.html");

    socket.on("connect", function(){
        socket.emit('user_join', "Bob", room);
    });

    socket.on("update_chat", function(username, message){
        addChatMessage(username, message);
        messages.push({username : username, message : message});
    });
```

However, I think I am misunderstanding something either about the express routing, or the `io.connect()` line. If the room is being passed in the URL like this "/room/123", what should I be putting in the `io.connect()` line? Because the `socket.on('connect', function()...` part is not being called at all so its not connecting for some reason.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I think you should just do `io.connect("http://mydomain.com:3000")`

Comment: Oh that seems to have done the trick! Just what I was looking for, thank you.